# std::stringstream.str() outputs garbage

Tags: c++, opencv, std

I need to save a bunch of image files with numbered indices. I am trying to construct these filenames using a stringstream. However, stringstream.str() does not seem to return the filename, but rather returns some garbage.

Here is the code:

```
std::stringstream filename;
filename << filepath << fileindex << ".png";
bool ret = imwrite(filename.str(),frame, compression_params);
fileindex++;
printf("Wrote %s\n", filename.str());
```

Here is the output from one execution:

```
Wrote ╠±0
Wrote ╠±0
Wrote ╠±0
Wrote ╠±0
```

Here is the output from another execution:

```
Wrote ░‗V
Wrote ░‗V
Wrote ░‗V
Wrote ░‗V
```

Any suggestions? Is imwrite is an opencv function, and I have [code]using namespace cv;[/code] at the top of the file - is there some interference between opencv and std?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass a non-POD type like `std::string` to a C-style variadic function like `printf`.

You could use C++ output:

```
std::cout << "Wrote " << filename.str() << '\n';
```

or, if you like old-school weirdness, extract the C-style string for C-style output:

```
printf("Write %s\n", filename.str().c_str());
```

Comment: Yeah, I feel it's better without the old-school weirdness - I'll omit printf whenever possible. Turns out the imwrite wasn't working because the folder didn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

`filename.str()` returns a `std::string` object. You can't `printf` it directly. Format `%s` requires C-style string. This should work

```
printf("Wrote %s\n", filename.str().c_str());
```

In any case, using C-style functions with C++ objects is not always the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can printf std::stringstream object using some helper functions:-

```
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>

template<typename T>
auto hp(T const & t){
    return t;
}
auto hp(std::string const & ss){
    return ss.c_str();
}
auto hp(std::ostringstream & ss){
    return ss.str();
}
template<typename ... Args>
void printer2(Args const&...args){
    printf(hp(args)...);
}
template<typename ... Args>
void printer(Args&&...args){
    printer2(hp(args)...);
}

int main() {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << "One";
    std::string str {"Two"};
    printer("%s %s %s %c %d", ss, str, "Three", '\n', 7);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rzvz76neE